# In VueJS how to print the v-for’s increment digit key as a suffix to a CSS class

Tags: for-loop, vuejs2, increment

I simply want to increment a **CSS class** based on the loop count using the `index` value as a suffix to a defined class `"classname nb"` to get `"classname nb1"`, `"classname nb2"`.

I'm able to print it as content using double curly brackets `{{ index }}` (*in my example below*) but I dont’t know what syntaxe to use within the Vue `:class` prop.

```html
<ol>
    <li v-for="index in 3" :key="index">
        <v-bind class="classname" :class="nb{ index }">
            classname nb{{ index }}
        </v-bind>
    </li>
</ol>
```

I expect these CSS classes on `<v-bing>` :

```
1. classname nb1
2. classname nb2
3. classname nb3
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer from a colleague...

First wrap the classname to index within **single quotes for class** ( `'…'` ), *for not conflicting with the `:class=""` double quotes*, followed by the plus sign (`+`) then the `index` key.

```html
<v-bind class="classname" :class="'nb' + index">
  {{ "nb" + index }}
</v-bind>
```

Gives

```html
<v-bind class="classname nb1"> nb1 </v-bind>
<v-bind class="classname nb2"> nb2 </v-bind>
<v-bind class="classname nb3"> nb3 </v-bind>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use template literals like this:

```
<ol>
<li v-for="index in [1,2,3]" :key="index">
    <v-bind class="classname" :class=`nb${index}`>
        classname nb{{ index }}
    </v-bind>
</li>
```

Comment: Ok thanks.It does work for my simplefied example but my real usage is for much greater loop then 3.